# Java Rate Limiter inside for loop, after acquire calling external api(which has throttling) not limiting rate

Tags: java, spring-boot, guava, throttling, rate-limiting

1. Please refer below code snippet. RateLimiter is used to restrict more than 10 calls in a second to external api. After rateLimiter.acquire() line, async method is called(core async task executor thread pool is 80 and max core pool size is 100 -> Can't Change). As per my understanding, rate limiter acquire line shouldn't allow more than 10 item to go to editItemAsync method so that externalApi.editItemProps line doesn't execute more than 10 times a second.
2. But during testing, its not the case & due to async externalApi.editItemProps is called more than 10 times in a second, hence giving throttling error. And also, completableFutures is used for response from service method.
3. The question is, Does Ratelimiter acquire works when the call after that line is async, or it only works for sync?
   **OR** the understanding isn't correct in term of how ratelimiter works. Because I tried with different ratelimiter permitsPerSeconds like 5/7. But out of 10 tries, some or the other time this fails. (It doesn't guarantee to be rate limiting.)
   Thanks.

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;
class ItemProcess {
 private final RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(10.0);
 void itemChecking(List<Item> items) {
  try {
   List<CompletableFuture<Item>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Item item : items) {
    if (item.isExpired()) { // print
    } else {
     rateLimiter.acquire();
     completableFutures.add(service.editItemAsync(item));
    }
   }// for ends
   CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()])).get();
  } catch(Exception e) {
  }
 }
}

// Both classes are different layer, so async is working
class Service {
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<Item> editItemAsync(Item item) {
    editItem(item);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(item);
  }
  
  void editItem(Item item) {
    // calling external api & it has throttling of 10 requests per seconds.
    externalApi.editItemProps(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: it is pretty late but do you have the test result?